# Hive select statement from spark shell

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, hive, data-analysis

I tried to run a select query on a hive table through spark shell. this is my code :

```
scala >import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext                                                                                                                     
scala >val sqlContext = new HiveContext(sc)    
scala >val df = sqlContext.sql("select count(*) from timeserie")
scala >df.head
```

but I got an error when I execute any read command (`df.head`, `df.count`, `df.show`) .
this is the error :

```
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$TreeNodeException: execute, tree:                                                                                          
Exchange SinglePartition                                                                                                                                                
+- *(1) HashAggregate(keys=[], functions=[partial_count(1)], output=[count#13L])                                                                                        
+- HiveTableScan HiveTableRelation `default`.`timeserie`, 
org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe, [data#0, temperature#1, hum#2]                         

at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$.attachTree(package.scala:56)                                                                                         
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec.doExecute(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:119)                                                               
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
... 49 elided                                                                                                                                                         
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Not a file: hdfs://sandbox- 
hdp.hortonworks.com:8020/warehouse/tablespace/managed/hive/timeserie/delta_0000001_0000001_0000              
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:337)                                                                                       
at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:200)                                                                                                  
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:253)                                                                                                
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:251)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
... 73 more
```

ps : when I execute the `show tables` query I get the result without error

show create table timeserie : 
[show create table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCM8z.png)

and hdfs dfs -ls ../../warehouse/tablespace/managed/hive/bdp.db/timeserie : 
[hdfs dfs -ls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQTov.png)

result of hdfs dfs -ls -R ../../warehouse/tablespace/managed/hive/bdp.db/serie/ : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gi7JL.png)

Comment: Could you please run msck repair table.. What kind of तबके is this?

Comment: I didn't quite get your answer. But how do I run this msck?

Comment: `msck repair table <table_name>` run this command on your table name. replace `<table_name>` with your table name.

Comment: I had this mistake : 
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Operation not allowed: MSCK REPAIR TABLE only works on partitioned tables: `default`.`timeserie`;

Comment: What kind of table do you have... Show your create table syntax

Comment: I created it through the http://sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:30800 interface. I use the hdp cloudera machine.

Comment: Please post the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE timeserie` and also `hdfs dfs -ls warehouse/tablespace/managed/hive/timeserie/`

Comment: I add them into the question as pictures

Comment: The problem is with the directory structure of your table location. There is a directory `delta_0000001_0000001_0000` under the table location, Is this intended? Can you post the output of `hdfs dfs -ls -R /warehouse/tablespace/managed/hive/bdp.db/serie/` to get the idea of how your files are stored.

Comment: I add them into the question

Comment: Your data actually exists under `/warehouse/tablespace/managed/hive/bdp.db/serie/delta_0000001_0000001_0000/`. Recreate the table with this location.

Comment: the data are already created when I query it with hive cli everything is fine but with spark shell no